# Serial Ports Context Manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

Is the following a reasonable approach?

```
with SerialPorts() as serial_ports:
    in= SerialPort("COM1")
    serial_ports.add(in)
    out = SerialPort("COM2")
    serial_ports.add(out)

    # use in and out
```

where `SerialPorts` and `SerialPort` implement the context manager interface.

`SerialPorts.exit()` loops through the added serial ports calling their `exit()`. `SerialPort`'s `exit()` closes the serial port.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this code:

```
class A(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print "exit", self

class B(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print "exit", self
        raise Exception

with A() as a, B() as b:
    pass
```

you will see that both `__exit__`s get called even if one raises an error (with either `A` before `B` and `B` before `A`).

If you call both `__exit__`s from a single collective `__exit__`, if the first has an error the second `__exit__` won't get called.

Use nested context managers instead, assuming you have a small fixed number of them.

Comment: I agree that nested context managers would be a better solution than a single SerialPorts manager to cover multiple instances of SerialPort.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
with SerialPorts("COM1", "COM2") as (inport, outport):
    # use inport and outport
```

`in` is a [reserved word](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in python, and using it as a variable name will result in a SyntaxError.

---

**Edit**: Here's one possible implementation (untested):

```
import serial
from contextlib import contextmanager 

@contextmanager
def serial_ports(*args):
    ports = [serial.Serial(arg) for arg in args]
    try:
        yield ports
    finally:
        for port in ports:
            port.close()

with serial_ports('COM1', 'COM2') as (inp, outp):
    print 'inp:', inp.isOpen(), 'outp:', outp.isOpen()

print 'inp:', inp.isOpen(), 'outp:', outp.isOpen()
```

But I defer to @agf on this one. His suggestion is much better for your case.

Comment: Since he's probably not worried about errors while trying to close the port, just while using it, this is most likely fine in practice, if there are enough ports that you don't want to specify them all in the `with`, as you can do `serial_ports(*port_list) as ports:` with this method.